# How to interrupt Tornado coroutine

Tags: python, exception, tornado, yield, coroutine

Suppose I have two functions that work like this:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def f():
    for i in range(4):
        print("f", i)
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(0.5)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def g():
    yield tornado.gen.sleep(1)
    print("Let's raise RuntimeError")
    raise RuntimeError
```

In general, function `f` might contain endless loop and never return (e.g. it can process some queue).

What I want to do is to be able to interrupt it, at any time it yields.

The most obvious way doesn't work. Exception is only raised after function `f` exits (if it's endless, it obviously never happens).

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    try:
        yield [f(), g()]
    except Exception as e:
        print("Caught", repr(e))

    while True:
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

Output:

```
f 0
f 1
Let's raise RuntimeError
f 2
f 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 812, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  <...>
  File "test.py", line 16, in g
    raise RuntimeError
RuntimeError
```

That is, exception is only raised when both of the coroutines return (both futures resolve).

This's partially solved by `tornado.gen.WaitIterator`, but it's buggy ([unless I'm mistaken](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1429)). But that's not the point.

It still doesn't solve the problem of interrupting existing coroutines. Coroutine continues to run even though the function that started it exits.

**EDIT**: it seems like coroutine cancellation is something not really supported in Tornado, unlike in Python's asyncio, where you can easily throw `CancelledError` at every yield point.

Comment: Does the normal `generator.throw` function not work with Tornado coroutines? And, if not, is there no documented replacement that does? (For `yield from`-based coroutines, as in the stdlib's `asyncio`, there are some tricky issues around that, but for `yield`-based trampolined coroutines that shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: `tornado.gen.coroutine` decorator makes function return a future instead of a generator, and underlaying generator doesn't seem to be exposed. Tornado futures don't support `cancel()` method, either (it's implemented as always returning `False`).

Comment: Oh well, I guess I don't know Tornado well enough to help here. Hopefully someone else does. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you [use WaitIterator according to the instructions](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.WaitIterator), and use a [toro.Event](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#event) to signal between coroutines, it works as expected:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop

import toro

stop = toro.Event()


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def f():
    for i in range(4):
        print("f", i)

        # wait raises Timeout if not set before the deadline.
        try:
            yield stop.wait(timedelta(seconds=0.5))
            print("f done")
            return
        except toro.Timeout:
            print("f continuing")


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def g():
    yield tornado.gen.sleep(1)
    print("Let's raise RuntimeError")
    raise RuntimeError


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    wait_iterator = tornado.gen.WaitIterator(f(), g())
    while not wait_iterator.done():
        try:
            result = yield wait_iterator.next()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error {} from {}".format(e, wait_iterator.current_future))
            stop.set()
        else:
            print("Result {} received from {} at {}".format(
                result, wait_iterator.current_future,
                wait_iterator.current_index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

For now, `pip install toro` to get the Event class. Tornado 4.2 will include Event, [see the changelog](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/next.html#new-modules-tornado-locks-and-tornado-queues).

Comment: That would work, but that essentially means that I must place interruption points manually (in addition to yield points), create event object and somehow associate it with the coroutine, etc. Not very convenient. I believe that your solution might be improved with some decorators and helper functions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5, [Tornado runs on `asyncio` event loop](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v5.0.0.html).

> On Python 3, the `IOLoop` is always a wrapper around the `asyncio` event loop, and `asyncio.Future` and `asyncio.Task` are used instead of their Tornado counterparts.

Hence you can use `asyncio` Task cancellation, i.e. [`asyncio.Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel).

Your example with a queue reading while-true loop, might look like this.

```py
import logging
from asyncio import CancelledError

from tornado import ioloop, gen


async def read_off_a_queue():
    while True:
        try:
            await gen.sleep(1)
        except CancelledError:
            logging.debug('Reader cancelled')
            break
        else:
            logging.debug('Pretend a task is consumed')

async def do_some_work():
    await gen.sleep(5)
    logging.debug('do_some_work is raising')
    raise RuntimeError                     

async def main():
    logging.debug('Starting queue reader in background')
    reader_task = gen.convert_yielded(read_off_a_queue())    
    try:
        await do_some_work()
    except RuntimeError:
        logging.debug('do_some_work failed, cancelling reader')
        reader_task.cancel()
        # give the task a chance to clean up, in case it
        # catches CancelledError and awaits something
        try:
            await reader_task            
        except CancelledError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')        
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

If you run it, you should see:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:root:Starting queue reader in background
DEBUG:root:Pretend a task is consumed
DEBUG:root:Pretend a task is consumed
DEBUG:root:Pretend a task is consumed
DEBUG:root:Pretend a task is consumed
DEBUG:root:do_some_work is raising
DEBUG:root:do_some_work failed, cancelling reader
DEBUG:root:Reader cancelled
```

Answer (score -1):

***Warning***: This is not a working solution. Look at the commentary. Still if you're new (as myself), this example can show the logical flow. Thanks @nathaniel-j-smith and @wgh

What is the difference using something more primitive, like global variable for instance?

```
import asyncio


event = asyncio.Event()
aflag = False


async def short():
    while not aflag:
        print('short repeat')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('short end')


async def long():
    global aflag

    print('LONG START')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    aflag = True
    print('LONG END')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(long(), short())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It is for **asyncio**, but I guess the idea stays the same. This is a semi-question (why **Event** would be better?). Yet solution yields exact result author needs:

```
LONG START
short repeat
short repeat
short repeat
LONG END
short end
```

UPDATE:
this [slides](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f15/www/lectures/15-ecf-signals.pdf) may be really helpful in understanding core of a problem.

Comment: This requires coroutine to constantly poll the global variable, which is not an option since the coroutine might be blocked on network IO in other library.

Comment: I don't get. They use same shared memory. Yet there would be a problem in one thread. Can you please share any blog post about it or briefly describe, why there is a problem of using very lightweight primitive in a shared memory for 1 process? Could be usage of a ContextVars be preferable, or there is no difference conceptually? Thanks @WGH

Comment: Just imagine what would happen if it wasn't `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, but rather `await asyncio.sleep(1000)`, or `await fetch("http://slow.example.com/")`.

Comment: You just repeat your previous concern of a slow operation. But still didn't answer (or I don't understand), why polling variable from the same process would be cost inefficient.

Comment: The problem is that if you only check the variable after each operation finishes, then it might take a very long time before the function notices that the global variable has been set. If you want to interrupt it now, then waiting 1000 seconds isn't so nice :-). On the other hand, if you want it to be interrupted quickly, then the function has to constantly poll the global variable at a high frequency, and that's inefficient.

Comment: Oooooh, Now I get it. Thanks @NathanielJ.Smith. I was afraid I didn't understand concept of a coroutines and though that's some issue with an OS or Networking. But it's just a simple logical flow!